# NestedScrollView with ImageView and Recycler view

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

The Recycler view gets scrolled inside imageview and imageview stays stationary.My requirement is to scroll both the views when recyclerview is scrolled.The xml I have written is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/profileLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@color/primary_color"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_user"
                app:border_color="#ffffff"
                app:border_width="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fullNameTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_color" />
        </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/drawerList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

How do I achieve such type of scrolling?

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare check out this code it may help you

Comment: @LalitPratapSingh NestedScrollView in that library is used with textview wrapped inside Cardview !Thats not what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `CoordinatorLayout` for this purpose where you can put your circular `ImageView` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` & also you can use it to set your title instead of your `TextView` which is specified by `fullNameTextView` id as below:

**Xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/collapsible_app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_banner"
            app:contentScrim="@color/background_content_frame"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_user"
                app:border_color="#ffffff"
                app:border_width="2dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/collapsible_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/drawerList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
 CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
 collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Title");
```

Reference: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_offer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/kuhnyamain"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```